# How do i schedule the built-in windows memory diagnostics from a server core installation?

Tags: memory, windows-server-2019, windows-server-core

How do i schedule the built-in windows memory diagnostics from a server core installation?

mdsched.exe does not seem to be included in Server Core 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command worked for me on Hyper-V Server 2019: -

```
bcdedit /bootsequence {memdiag}
```

It sets the memory diagnostic to boot and execute at the next server restart. After exiting the diagnostic the server will restart to Windows again. Microsoft documentation for bcdedit is here [BCDEdit Options Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcd-boot-options-reference). The `{memdiag}` is a well-known boot entry identifier, which you can find with: -

```
bcdedit /? id
```